# Is there a hot key available or configurable in Xcode for the "back button"?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

The backbutton in Xcode is super useful for me, especially when I CMD+CLICK to see a declaration, but I always have to use the mouse to click the arrow back button.  Is this configurable to hot key?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^⌘← unless I redefined that :P

Press "⌘," and go to Key Bindings to see the whole list. You can type "back" in the search box.

Comment: Right on!  Thanks man, I looked through the keymap settings last night, but I think all of the "back" choices did not sound right to me... should have tried them all!  Thx again!

Comment: As of Xcode 12.4 rebinding the "back" and "forward" actions is broken. Thanks apple!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Logitech mouse with physical back/forward buttons. By default these buttons map to ⌘[ and ⌘]. Unfortunately these keystrokes default in Xcode to Shift Left (outdent) and Shift Right (indent), which are *not* what I expect when using my mouse.

So I just remapped ⌘[ to Go Back and ⌘] to Go Forward, though I also had to remove a few conflicting key bindings in order to do it.

Works great now, *and* I don't have to install any horrible Logitech software (stick to hardware, Logitech!). ;)